# 301 or 302 redirects for not logged in user?

Tags: seo, redirects

Users that are logged in have access to their own page `site.com/club/their-name-here`. If they're not logged in I 302 redirect that link to `site.com/club/` where there's the log in form.

I kept reading about this and it seems that some say it's ok, some recommend that it should be with a 301 redirect.

Will I get penalized for this?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do I wouldn't use a 301 for this. This will cause bots to all think your pages are all moved to your login page. While a 302 whould be a good pragmatic choice since it technically has more support in browsers you may want to go with a 303 and be just a little less ambiguous about how you want this handled.

Wiki has a much more detailed description of the difference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Answer (score 0):

Is `site.com/club/their-name-here` a public page? It seems if they are not logged in and redirect to `/club/` which shows a login then it is only visible to users logged in? Why not create a universal login page at `example.com/login` and once authenticated redirect to `site.com/club/their-club-name` Or for that matter `site.com/their-name`

The redirect you have isn't bad since `/club/` most likely doesn't have any content, so 301 redirecting isn't taking away any link juice to a page with any value, so there isn't much to worry about in that regard.

Is `/club` really needed? Or is it there because of how the website and application were developed? Would your website still make sense to visitors and users if it were just `site.com/their-name`?